# How to stop an activity to be accessed from another app?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In my app I have two activities:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
```

So my `SecondActivity` can be accessed from another app. I think it's a security issue, so how can I stop this? Is this somehow related with exported setup?

Comment: What do you mean by *accessed from another app*? Why would it be a security issue?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but maybe this will help: https://developer.android.com/topic/security/best-practices#disallow-access-to-your-apps-content-providers

Comment: @JakubLicznerski The second activity can be accessed from another app. Why it isn't a security issue?

Comment: @rafvasq Thanks I'll check that resource.

Answer (score 2):

Within three steps you can do it.

1. define a permission (which is only available to applications having your signature)
2. define that your application uses your defined permission
3. require that permission for the activities you want protected. (Be careful to not require it for your main launch activity).

---

```
<!-- to define a permission -->
<permission
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.example.MYPERMISSION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.MYPERMISSION" />

<!-- to define an activity which can only be started through internal code -->
<activity android:name="..."
          android:permission="com.example.MYPERMISSION" >
    ...
</activity>
```

Comment: right, without that permission, your MainActivity can't access SecondActivity according to your app's two activities.

Comment: Thanks for answering but what is actually `MYPERMISSION`, a what, a .XML file or what?

Comment: My package name is `package="com.mydomain.myapp"` the permission will be: `<permission
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.mydomain.MYPERMISSION"/>` and that's it?

Comment: MYPERMISSION is a String. May be this will help : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining

Comment: Please show me an example of the String MYPERMISSION. Or how to create and where to create that String.

Comment: Please Check this slide you will get a clear concept . https://www.owasp.org/images/c/ca/ASDC12-An_InDepth_Introduction_to_the_Android_Permissions_Modeland_How_to_Secure_MultiComponent_Applications.pdf

Comment: should user also grant this permission at the time of installing ?

Comment: i cannot run the activity from same app as it says the permission is not present .
users-permission is added in manifest

Answer (score 2):

android:exported = false in AndroidManifest inside activity tag should do the work

Comment: And this is it? There is no need to all those permission stuff from Prapon's answer?

Comment: you can add permission when you want only certain 3rd party app to be able to start your activity. Exported = false means no one other than your app can start your activity

Comment: So if I want only my app to be able to access my second activity, setting `android:exported = false` to my SecondActivity will be enough, right?